# Gradient from Theano expression for filter visualization in Keras

Tags: python, scipy, theano, deep-learning, keras

For a ConvNet it can be interesting to find the norm-bounded input that maximizes the activity of a single conv. filter as a way to [visualize the filters](http://igva2012.wikispaces.asu.edu/file/view/Erhan+2009+Visualizing+higher+layer+features+of+a+deep+network.pdf). I'd like to do this in the deep learning package Keras. This could be done using a black box optimization algorithm with the code from the [FAQ](http://keras.io/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer).

```
# with a Sequential model
get_3rd_layer_output = theano.function([model.layers[0].input],
                                       model.layers[3].get_output(train=False))
layer_output = get_3rd_layer_output(X)
```

However, it would be a substantially easier optimization task if I had the gradient. How can I extract the gradient from the Theano expression and input it into a Python optimization library such as Scipy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print out the gradient as described [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/gradients.html) and hand-code it into Scipy.  You can also do the optimization in Theano - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29643793/1397061).

However, probably the most straight-forward approach is to create a function `get_gradients()` that uses `theano.grad()` to return the gradients of the filters with respect to an input, then call `scipy.optimize.minimize` with `jac=get_gradients`.  According to the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html):

> jac : bool or callable, optional Jacobian (gradient) of objective
>   function. [...] jac can also be a callable returning the gradient of
>   the objective. In this case, it must accept the same arguments as fun.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the basic idea behind `theano.grad()`, but how would I extract the gradients with respect to the loss for a Keras model? Based on https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/conv_filter_visualization.py I've seen how this can be done using some input `X_train`, but I haven't figured how to do this for the loss. My two issues are 1) I cannot seem to extract the loss function as connected to the network 2) This new function needs both `X_train` and `y_train`, which I can't seem to provide in the right way.

Comment: Keras already computes the gradients of the loss with respect to each layer, during backpropagation.  But don't you want the gradients of an intermediate layer with respect to the input?

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry, it's been a while since I asked the question. Your answer solves it. My current issue is how to extract the gradients across all parameters wrt. the loss as I want to examine the need for gradient clipping. Is that easy to get from the backprop provedure as implemented in Keras?

Comment: I don't think this is built into Keras, but you can follow the procedure used by Keras's optimizers - take a look at the get_gradients method of the Optimizer class at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py#L52.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with tensorflow as the backend? I get all zeros for the gradient.

`model` is a simple feedforward model.

Compute the activation of the first unit in the first layer:
`activation_of_unit_0 = K.tf.slice(
    model.layers[1].output,
    begin=[0, 0], size=[0, -1])`

Compute gradient with respect to input:
`gradient_unit0_wrt_input = K.tf.gradients(
    activation_of_unit_0,
    model.input)[0]`

Evaluating on some `data` gives all 0:
`with K.get_session().as_default():
    print(gradient_unit0_wrt_input.eval(
        feed_dict={model.input: data,}))`

Comment: @CharlieBrummitt: Sorry, I haven't used the tensorflow backend.